# Browser links are not showing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I don't no what happened to VS,now it is not showing Browsers list.
How to overcome from this problem please suggest me.

Comment: Is this an upgraded solution? If so, did you add in the MVC5 projectguids?

Answer (score 2):

Include screenshot of the project / solution list.  I believe somehow you are opening a .csproj project file for a non MVC application even though it has all the code files that look like a MVC application.  For instance someone may have created a windows form application and imported all the MVC / .cs files from a MVC ASP .NET project.

If you included that screenshot we could see the icon next to the project to rule that out as a potential cause.

Alternatively you can try reset your visual studio 2013 settings by doing the following:

1.On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.

2.On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset all settings and then click Next.

3.If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save my current settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

4.In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a settings collection from the list.

5.Click Finish.